# Adding -ObjC flag in xcode

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, google-street-view

I am trying to integrate google Street View Image API into my iOS app, but in order to use their SDK I need to use the -ObjC linker flag to load their category methods. Everything works perfectly without the linker, but when I add the -ObjC flag in Xcode  I get:

ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to link Metal.framework, but Xcode can't find it for some reason. Perhaps the path is wrong, or you're using an SDK where Metal isn't available. Either fix the Path/SDK issue or remove Metal.framework from the Link Binary With Libraries phase.

Comment: @Jasarien how i search metal framework in sdk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once check whether all the files are added correctly into your App.check in BuildPhases also if anything is missed.Hope this helps.

Comment: once go through this link @farid                        https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/153

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Based on their discussion we can understand

Comment: same problem in that link also .once update your version and check it if it works.And also go through that complete link clearly so that your issue may be solved

Comment: If you find any other way just post your answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the -ObjC flag both in "Debug" and "Release".
Sometimes by mistake we add it in just "Debug".

Comment: yes i add the -ObjC flag both in "Debug" and "Release".