# Add -ObjC Linker Flag build to fail

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have added the -ObjC linker flag (to add the street view api),it's work fine on simulator but it causes the build to fail on device.

ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this @Developer [Adding -ObjC flag in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497957/adding-objc-flag-in-xcode/28498863?noredirect=1#comment45318988_28498863)

and go through this link:https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/153

hope it helps

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: update your version and check if the issue is occurring again @Developer

Comment: once Delete derived data first click on xcode in that window->organizer->projects and delete them it will clean

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: once update your Xcode to newer version Xcode 6.1.1 and run your app

Comment: ,ok i can update the version,but i m not clear about this why they r running perfect on simulator which is iphone retina (3.5 inch).not  on iphone 4s?

Comment: have you added all libraries clearly.once check in Build Phases->Link Binary with libraries